# How to use image labeled resulted from Image labeler App (black image) to calculate jaccard Index?

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, label, image-segmentation, semantic-segmentation

I used the pixel label from the image labeler App and after I finished labeling I used Export to file . Then I opened the file that was created called PixelLabeData and I found the labeled image is totally black and the label not shown, I understood that I had to use the following code to let label appear

```
figure; 
[i, m] = imread('Label_1.png');
imshow(i,m)
```

but then I want to use this labeled image in the following equation to calculate jaccrad index, but the image is totally black

```
A = logical(imread('7001-236.png'));
BW_groundTruth =logical(imread('Label_1.png'));
similarity = jaccard(squeeze(A(:,:,1)), BW_groundTruth)
```

similarity =
0.0925     because label image is black
So how do I fix it?